# How to prevent ngOnInIt from being read again?

Tags: angular

I created a form with an option to view detailed data. When viewing detailed data, the user will automatically be redirected to another form. When exiting the detail form, return to the initial form. How can I return to the initial form so that ngOnInIt doesn't need to be read again? So that the condition of the initial form is not like just opening the form.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code that you may share will help.

Comment: just pass the queryParams and handle both cases

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition in ngOnInit() to check if it is the initial load or the user has returned from the details page.

As Indraraj mentioned, you can pass QueryParams to handle the cases.

*Note - Please always add a demo or sample code so that it is helpful for others to understand the question.*